# Returning errors from C# web service to Angular application

Tags: c#, angular, web-services

I’m writing an Angular application that utilizes a C# web service to get information from a SOAP API (Angular client makes a request to the service which interacts with the wsdl and returns data).

My question is about best practices for handling errors within the C# service. When an error occurs, I want the service to return the error so that the end user is notified of a problem. However, returning the error text gets a bit clunky on the client side, and when exceptions are caught within the service, the angular client doesn’t detect an issue. As of now, I have the service logging errors and then throwing an uncaught exception, which results in angular’s catchError function being executed and displaying a user-friendly error message. It works quite well, but I wasn’t sure if this is a good practice or the best way to do it. Is this a bad practice, and if so, what would a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

On the backend your web service should return errors with an http status code in the 400 or 500 range so that the angular client will register these responses as errors. Additionally as best practice you'll want to make sure these errors are being logged somewhere so that you can find and resolve issues as they occur before any user reports it.

On the client-side you'll want to catch and handle (recover from) any errors that you're able to. Any errors that you can't handle should at least display a user friendly message to the user. If you're being consistent about how you're formatting error messages (which you should be) then you can usually define some kind of global error handler to do that kind of formatting and throw it up in a toaster.

Comment: Right, so it is returning a 400 or 500 range error depending on what happened. However, its doing that by throwing an uncaught exception which I wasn’t sure was good practice.